# Perform a function on values in multiple columns based on value in one cell using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a sheet of data and am attempting to check column E10 TO I610 to see if the values in there are more than 11538 and the value in cell J5 is "weekly". If the conditions are true,  add the values that are more than 11538 and multiply them by 8.4. How do I go about doing this?

Not too strong with vba so please bear with me.

```
If schedType = "Weekly" And Range("E10,I610").Value > 11538 Then
Range("H6").Value = "WOW"
ElseIf schedType = "Monthly" Then
Range("H6").Value = "10"
End If
```

I tried the above way to achieve what I want. Though the code above wont do the exact calculations im after, its just a test. Like I said, I'm attempting to search the range E10 to I610 for any values greater than 11538, then total them and finally find 8.4% of the total.
Its a bit complicated and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It helps us to help you if you include the code that you have tried and how it is not working for you. [ask]

Comment: If schedType = "Weekly" And Range("E10,I610").Value > 11538 Then
                    Range("H6").Value = "WOW"
                    ElseIf schedType = "Monthly" Then
                    Range("H6").Value = "10"
                    End If

Comment: this doesn't work period. If I place 11539 in E11, nothing happens. Not to strong with VBA so im at a loss here. Really what i want to do is add all those values greater than 11538 in the range E10 to I610 then fine 8.4% of the total.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for a lot of reasons, not the least of which is this:

`Range("E10,I610").Value`

For starters, `Range("E10,I610")` is a range of **only two cells**, you guessed it: `E10` and `I10`.  Use a colon to create a continuous range object, `Range("E10:I610")`.  Furthermore, the `.Value` property of a multi-cell range will always, only return the value in the top, left cell.

So, since the value of `E10` was not `> 11538`, the first `If` statement returns `False`, and the rest of your code within that block is omitted.

Then, it will continues to fail because you have not structured the code correctly.

There are several ways to work with multiple cells/ranges, I will give you one example which is not very efficient, but it will work for your purposes.  I will use a `For each` loop to iterate over every cell in the `Range("E10:I610")`, and then check those values against `11538`, summing the values greater than `11538`.

```
Sub TotalCells()

Dim schedType as String
Dim rng as Range
Dim cl as Range
Dim myTotal as Double

Set rng = Range("E10:I610")
schedType = Range("J5").Value

'## Check what schedType we are working with:
If schedType = "Weekly" Then
    For each cl in rng.Cells
        If cl.Value > 11538 Then myTotal = myTotal + cl.Value
    Next
    '## Multiply the sum by 8.4%
    myTotal = 0.084 * myTotal
    '## Display the result:
    MsgBox "The weekly total is: " & myTotal, vbInformation

ElseIf schedType = "Monthly" Then
    ' You can put another set of code here for Monthly calculation.

End If

## Print the total on the worksheet, cell H6
Range("H6").Value = myTotal

End Sub
```

As I said, this is not efficient, but it illustrates a good starting point.  You could also use formulas like `CountIfs` or `SumIfs` or use the worksheet's `AutoFilter` method and then sum the visible cells, etc.

In the future, it is always best to post all, or as much of your code as possible, including the declaration of variables, etc., so that we don't have to ask questions like "What type of variable is `schedType`?"

Comment: Thank you very much David. Point taken with me posting as much code as possible. Sorry for not posting more. I will use your example and try to expand on it. Again thank you very much David.

Comment: * its still not working right*  << You're going to need to explain yourself. I don't have a crystal ball and I can't read your mind. What  isn't working right? Is there an error? If there is an error what is the error and which line raises it? If it's not an error, describe what's happening and why you think that is not correct.